# Integrating multiple times.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, integration

I am having problem in integrating the equation below. If I integrate it w.r.t `x` then w.r.t `y` and then w.r.t `z`, the answers comes out to be 0 but the actual answer is `52`. Please help out. Thanks
[image]

Comment: Start with integrating w.r.t. $x$ and treat $y,z$ as constants, $ \int C +Ax^2 dx $. Then continue...

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{align}
\int_1^3 (6yz^3+6x^2y)\,dx &= \left[6xyz^3+2x^3y\right]_{x=1}^3
=12yz^3+52y
\\
\int_0^1 (12yz^3+52y)\,dy &=\left[6y^2z^3+26y^2\right]_{y=0}^1
=6z^3+26
\\
\int_{-1}^1 (6z^3+26)\,dz &= \left[\frac{3}{2}z^4+26z\right]_{z=-1}^1 = 52 .
\end{align}$$